# Jquery image uploader

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and facing this problem:

I have this grid of circles in which I am using an image uploader function on clicking on a small button inside the div.

I want to put the image in that div from which I clicked the button but I always get the image in the first div.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class='content'>

  <section class='example'>
    <div class='gridly'>
        <div class='brick small'>
            <div id="output"></div>
            <a class="topopup" href="#">Z</a> 
            <a class='delete' href='#'>&times;</a>

      </div>
      <div class='brick small'>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <a class="topopup" href="#">Z</a> 
        <a class='delete' href='#'>&times;</a>
      </div>
      <div class='brick small'>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <a class="topopup" href="#">Z</a> 
        <a class='delete' href='#'>&times;</a>
      </div>
      <div class='brick small'>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <a class="topopup" href="#">Z</a> 
        <a class='delete' href='#'>&times;</a>
      </div>
      <div class='brick small'>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <a class="topopup" href="#">Z</a> 
        <a class='delete' href='#'>&times;</a>
      </div>
      <div class='brick small'>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <a class="topopup" href="#">Z</a> 
        <a class='delete' href='#'>&times;</a>
      </div>
      </div>

    <p class='actions'>
      <a class='add button' href='#'>Add</a>
    </p>
  </section>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:   '#output',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
        success:       afterSuccess,  // post-submit callback 
        resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
    }; 

    $('#MyUploadForm').submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);        
        // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
        return false; 
    }); 
}); 

function afterSuccess() {
    $('#submit-btn').show(); //hide submit button
    $('#loading-img').hide(); //hide submit button
}    
$('#submit-btn').hide(); //hide submit button
$('#loading-img').show(); //hide submit button
$("#output").html("");
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle with the error?

Comment: http://www.dropzonejs.com/ is nice.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the div with `output` id.

Id should be unique in your html.

You are using it in your script (`target:   '#output'`) option

`$("#output")`  <-- get the first element that match the condition (first div with `output` id)

change

```
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="output"></div> and so on
```

with

```
<div id="output1"></div>
<div id="output2"></div>
<div id="output3"></div>
```

Get it with jquery in this way

`$("#output1")`

and in your options change `target` parameter

refer [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) for documentation